# create hyperlink on part of image

Tags: html, css

I have a background image in my footer that has a number of different images inside it. I want to create links to the respective websites of each of the images using html or css but I don't know how. I was told that it can be done in this way though. Is this possible, or am i going to need to split the image into multiple ones?
[image]

Comment: why dont you separate the images and keep the images in position using CSS? that would be easier..

Comment: I'll do that if I must, but I'm wondering if its possible without it

Comment: I dont think that would be easier to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HTML Map tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

An example would be:

```
<img src="GJ7SG.png" alt="" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="788, 2, 867, 37" alt="Sun" href="someurl.htm"/>
    <area shape="rect" coords="608, 1, 719, 37" alt="Sun" href="anotherurl.htm" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="374, 0, 501, 39" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="168, 0, 312, 38" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="1, 7, 87, 39" />
</map>
```

You will have to do some playing around to get it how you want but that should get you started.

Add the href to each rectangle. You can generate the map here: 
https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/s/u/summerstyle/365ccfd644f2b008c33f0046d2ba1a8f/summer-html-image-ma_1355318513_demo_package/index.html

Comment: Are the co-ordinates relative to the parent element or are they absolute?

Comment: They're absolute to the image, this won't be too good if your background image is responsive.

Comment: Its not, so long as its not absolute to the page its what I'm looking for

Comment: That should be good then. For more accurate results, it might be better to have the image not as a background but in a div. Since you add the `usemap` to the image it will be relative to the image. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a HTML Image Map:

```
<img src="img" usemap="#mymap" />
<map name="mymap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,300" href="linkurl" title="sometitle" alt="Hovertext" />
    ...
</map>
```

You maybe have to add the image to the foreground for it to work